# Code optimization of recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, optimization

I am having a recursive function in C as shown below :

```
float U(int k, int h)
{
    h --;
    int r, s;
    float sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

    if (h == -1)
    {
        return (float) ((pow(-1, k)) / factorial(k));
    }

    else
    {
        for (r = 0; r <= k; r++)
        {
            for (s = 0; s <= h; s++)
            {
                sum1 += (r + 1) * (k - r + 1) * U(r + 1, h - s) * U(k - r + 1, s);
            }
        }
        for (r = 0; r <= k; r++)
        {
            for (s = 0; s <= h; s++)
            {
                sum2 += (k - r + 1) * (k - r + 2) * U(r, h - s) * U(k - r + 2, s);
            }
        }
        return (float) ((sum1 + sum2) / (h + 1));
    }
}
```

I wish to optimize the code as the function takes a lot of time to calculate even not-so-large values like `U(10,13)`. Please give some suggestions along with code snippets(if possible).

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Read up on [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: pow used this way is really wasteful, use something like sign instead

Comment: pow(-1, evenNumber) = 1, and pow(-1, oddNumber) = -1 (I'm considering these numbers as int as they are in your code), so you can remove the pow() call... you can use a two-dimensional array to save the calculated values (u,k)... as Paul said, read about Memoization... you can also memoize factorial(k).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no code-review site.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Whilst this would be a perfectly OK Code Review question, it is also not Off-Topic for SO so I ask that you leave it here.

Comment: Why `float` and not `double` values?

Answer (score 1):

you can memorize the values in an array called `arr`. use better indentation as your code should be easily understandable. memset the array `arr` with `-1` before running the recursion. the code should look like this -

```
float arr[100][100];

float U(int k,int h)
{    
    h=h-1;
    int r,s;
    //float sum=0,sum1=0,sum2=0;

    if(h==-1)
    {
        float O_O = (float)(k%2!=0 ? -1:1);
        for(int _w=1; _w<=k; _w++)
            O_O/=(float)_w;
        return O_O;
    }

    if(arr[k][h]<-0.5)return arr[k][h];
    arr[k][h]=0;

    for(r=0;r<=k;r++)
    {
        for(s=0;s<=h;s++)
        {
            arr[k][h]+=(r+1)*(k-r+1)*U(r+1,h-s)*U(k-r+1,s);         
        }       
    }

    for(r=0;r<=k;r++)
    {
        for(s=0;s<=h;s++)
        {
            arr[k][h]+=(k-r+1)*(k-r+2)*U(r,h-s)*U(k-r+2,s);
        }
    }

    return (float)(arr[k][h]/(h+1));
}
```

Comment: I even sugest changing pow(-1, k) to (k < 0 ? -1 : 1) as k is an integer value. The resulting code would be: return (float) (k < 0 ? -1 : 1)/factorial(k);

Comment: yes showed an easier way. but i think its better to write (k%2!=0 ? -1:1). @Paulo

Comment: OMG. I didn't mean k < 0. Hehehe. I meant k%2 != 0 as you said.

Comment: Thanks @JishnuBanerjee. The code is running much more efficiently. But the output of U(k,h) for k>=13 and h>=11 is -1.#INF00 or +1.#INF00. i tried using double instead of float as well but there is no big difference.

Comment: because factorial(k) overflows! handle it :) @jitthakore

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee, I am using the following code for factorial:              `int fac_aux(int n, int acc) {
    return n < 1 ? acc : fac_aux(n - 1, acc * n);
}
 
int factorial(int n) {
    return fac_aux(n, 1);
}`.

Comment: forget your factorial function. look at my edited answer @jitthakore

Comment: The iterative approach used for the factorial function decreases the speed of execution considerably. The function for factorial which I have currently implemented is tail recursive. @JishnuBanerjee Please try to modify that function to remove overflow.

Comment: //The iterative approach used for the factorial function decreases the speed of execution considerably.// Sorry, but this line made me laugh out loud :p

anyway, to avoid overflow, you must have to do it iterative (yes, iterative must)